# First step in unit test python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm a beginner programmer and i'd like to start writing unit tests.
Here is a simple script to open json files:

```
import json  
from pprint import pprint

def get_notes_data(file_name):
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as open_file:
            return json.loads(open_file.read(), encoding='utf-8')
    except IOError:
        print "enter the correct path file"

data = get_notes_data('notes_data/notes.json')
pprint(data)
```

**Can I write a unit test for this little piece of code?**

Comment: To get started with unittesting in python you can refer [this example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example) in the docs. File read and write operations are usually best tested using python [mocks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). If you are new to programming then I would suggest you learn how to test simple functions first that don't do IO operations.

Comment: The basis behind unit testing is to make sure that for a given block of code; feeding it a controlled input gives back a predictable output with no side effects. In your example, a super simple unit test would be just running `get_notes_data` with different inputs (a file name, an object, null, etc) and making sure the output is expected. (Instead of printing an error, throw a catchable exception?) As the commenter above me stated, `mocks` is a good library to unit test your stuff.

Comment: thanks for the answers !